# Bcoin - running webpack-app issue

Tags: bcoin

I have cloned bcoin repo and installed webpack package. When trynig to run webpack-app I get the error below:

```
btc@ubuntu:~/bcoin/node_modules$ npm run webpack-app
npm ERR! missing script: webpack

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/btc/.npm/_logs/2020-11-18T08_55_31_312Z-debug.log
```

I have checked the **node_modules** folder inside the bcoin dir and couldn't find webpack-app package. Also, I excatly followed the instructions from https://bcoin.io/guides/browser

nodejs version: v10.19.0
npm version: 6.14.4

Answer (score 0):

bcoin does not use webpack anymore, and in fact the browser node as a proof of concept isn't really being maintained since it is practically very silly :-)

The webpack config files were removed form the repo [here](https://github.com/bcoin-org/bcoin/commit/0a71b445e0c12819e417bdf1df018fcb7bed4f0c) and [here](https://github.com/bcoin-org/bcoin/pull/741). If you *REALLY* want to try the browser node, you will need to checkout a git commit of bcoin from before those changes were made.

The bcoin library can still be compiled for browser usage in simple webapps and is still very useful for small applications like that. I refer you to this guide: https://bcoin.io/guides/webapp.html ...which uses [bpkg](https://github.com/chjj/bpkg) instead of webpack or browserify.

That browser-node guide should probably just be removed, or at least updated with a deprecation notice. If you feel like it you can make a PR to the website here: https://github.com/bcoin-org/bcoin-org.github.io

Feel free to join us on IRC #bcoin or on [Slack](https://bcoin.io/slack-signup.html) to chat more about this.

Comment: I would love to join the Slack channel but I don't have the email address from the specific domain name to be able to join. Would you hep to get that?

Comment: The link I posted https://bcoin.io/slack-signup.html is a webform that will send an invite link to any email address -- is that not working?

Comment: It worked properly and I just joined,. Appreciate you ;)